# Probability: Relationship between $\inf P(|X_n| > \epsilon)$ and $\inf E|X_n|$

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be random variables with $\mbox E X^2_j = 1$ for all $j$. Show that $\inf P[|X_n| > \epsilon] > 0$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ if and only if $\inf \mbox E |X_n| > 0$.

I have shown necessity, which is quite easy and doesn't use the hypothesis that $\mbox E X_j ^ 2 = 1$. I'm stuck on sufficiency, and can't seem to figure out how to work $\mbox E X_j ^ 2 = 1$ into anything useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1) $\Rightarrow$  : $E(|x|) = \int_{|x|\le e}|x| \; p(x) \, dx + \int_{|x|> e}|x| \; p(x) \, dx \ge \epsilon \; P(|x| >\epsilon )$

2) $\Leftarrow$  : Chebyshev's inequality

*Added:* Say we have $X$ with $E(X^2)=1$ and $E(|X|)\ge a > 0$ Let's apply Chebyshev to $Y=|X|$. $Var(Y) = E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2 \le 1- a^2$ Let's take (say) $\epsilon = a/2$. Then $P(Y<\epsilon) = P(a-Y > a/2)$ corresponds to a "tail", that we can bound strictly below 1, for example with the [one-sided Chebyshev inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Variant%3a_One-sided_Chebyshev_inequality).

Comment: I am not seeing how to get Chebyshev to help. It seems I need to bound $E[X_n]$ from above using $P(|X_n| > \epsilon)$. What should I apply Chebyshev to?

Comment: Perhaps we are speaking of opposites senses of the implication. To show that $E(|X|) >0$ given that $P(|X|>\epsilon)>d$  you use the first one.

Comment: I have the first result. I can't prove that if $\inf_n E[|X_n|] > 0$ then $\inf P(|X_n| > \epsilon) > 0$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, the Chebyshev hint not withstanding. If I can bound $E[|X_n|]$ from above using $P(|X_n| > \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon$ then I can prove the contrapositive, but that is as far as I can go. Perhaps I am completely on the wrong track? I can't see how to use Chebyshev to do this.

Comment: I expanded my hint - still not a complete proof.

Comment: Okay, I think I see now. So bound $P(Y < \epsilon)$ strictly below $1$ using Cantelli's Inequality which gives a lower bound on $P(Y \ge \epsilon)$, correct?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that knowing that $Y$ has mean  $a$ (or more) and  finite variance makes impossible that all its probability mass is concentrated below (say) $a/2$.